# Is it possible to use a SATA DOM drive as a recovery boot device, while also using the SATA DOM to house recovery VM OVA files?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, sata, recovery, supermicro

For some background, I have loaded oVirt (similar to CentOS) v4.2.2 on a SuperMicro server. The server is utilizing a RAID10 on qty 4 2TB drives -- however, the important part has to do with the SuperMicro SSD (SATA DOM). I am able to make this SATA DOM a recovery bootable drive for the OS using the command:

```
dd if=<name of OS ISO> of=/dev/sde
```

where /dev/sde is the device path for the SATA DOM. While I am able to make this a bootable drive, I was wondering if there was also a way to include OVA files on the SATA DOM, which could be mounted to the server and copied over to import VMs in a recovery case. I have tried creating multiple partitions, which then causes the device to no longer be bootable, and I have tried mounting the bootable SATA DOM to the server then adding the OVA files, but since the SATA DOM becomes an ISO9660 filesystem after copying over the oVirt ISO, it is not read/write mountable. Any help is appreciated. Will gladly attach /etc/fstab, lsblk, /dev/mapper/, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Per definition an ISO9660 image

- is read-only
- is a disk image (not a partition image) and as such can't coexist with other partitions.

So the only way to achieve what you want is, to change the ISO-File before "burning" it to the DOM. You can use `genisofs` and friends (or a GUI frontend such as `k4b` or `brasero`) to add additional files (including OVA files) to the ISO image and then write it with `dd`